# Disable nginx fastcgi cache URI normalization

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fastcgi

I have a wordpress website runing on nginx and i have activated fastcgi cache for it.
the problem is when a page get cached from nginx fastcgi the key name become like this

> KEY:
>   httpGETwww.mywebsite.com/test/%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A9

And when i try to Purge the page from the cache it doesn't recognize the URL because its normalized .
I think the problem is in

> fastcgi_cache_key $request_uri;

i have tried replacing it with

> fastcgi_cache_key $uri$is_args$args;

But thid didn't works at all all the keys URL has become www.mywebsite.com/index.php

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to purge a page from the cache?

Comment: Using this module https://github.com/nginx-modules/ngx_cache_purge

Comment: You should have filed a GitHub issue. But I can't find one that seems to correspond to what you describe. Which one is your GitHub issue?

Comment: I did https://github.com/nginx-modules/ngx_cache_purge/issues/21

Comment: Strange, I don't understand why they closed your issue. It seems to be a valid problem.

Comment: Yes and so far i can't find any solution for this problem anywhere !